# Javascript in chrome addon: do they support weak references?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, weak-references

I've written a JavaScript in which you can create some kind of objects. For development ease, I also created a web frontend in which all objects can be listed (and sorted, grouped etc.). Therefore, this frontend needs a list of all the objects.

Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't support weak references (only WeakMap and WeakRef, but no real weak references), so by keeping this list, none of the objects is garbage collected anymore.
 So I can't show the developer which objects are currently used.

Now, I want to provide this tool in an addon (like React Toolbar). 
Is it possible to use weak references in this privilidged code context? 
Also cool would be to be able to attach finalizers to objects.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Weak reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Weak_reference) documentation
in my searches but I haven't actually tried if it works for Chrome too.

Stated in [How do I make a class support weak references?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Weak_reference#How_do_I_make_a_class_support_weak_references.3F), to make class support weak references in Javascript, make sure that your  QueryInterface method returns your object for the `nsISupportsWeakReference` interface.

Going through the given documentation and trying sample codes might help.

Comment: hm, unfortunately I haven't found something for chrome yet, only the weak npm package, and that contains C code to be linked against the v8 sources

Comment: also, I think the Firefox version also doesn't work like it should because only privileged code (i.e. code written in the addon itself) can be weakly referenced according to my research.